# SQL Error: Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am receiving this error when trying to execute the query below. Any ideas or suggestions?

```
SELECT * 
FROM TB_Transactions ft
WHERE (SELECT SUM(IIF(ft2.TransferFromId = ft.TransferFromId, -ft2.Amount, ft2.Amount))
       FROM TB_Transactions ft2
       WHERE (ft2.TransferFromId = ft.TransferFromId
              OR ft2.TransferToId = ft.TransferToId)
         AND ft2.Created <= ft.Created) = 0;
```

I do not understand how to remake the request so that the error is gone.

Target: display all fields from the TB_Transactions for those transactions after which the sender's(TransferFromId) account had 0

Expected result:

```
14| 21| 10.00000000| 1|2022-07-07 08:05:40.200
```

- Because the first transaction (transfer 10) for account 14: 0-10=-10
- Second transaction (getting 20) for account 14: -10 +20=10
- Third transaction (transfer 10) for account 14: 10 -10=0
- Fourth transaction (transfer 10) for account 14: 0 -10=-10

If only I knew how to write the correct query. For account 14, a subquery that adds up to 0 maybe that will make it clearer.

[transaction list for account 14](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e21a193ad4f9bb37ea8eba1e0995c4b9)

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_Transactions]
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TransferFromId] [bigint] NULL,
    [TransferToId] [bigint] NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](21, 8) NOT NULL, 
    [Created] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_FG_Transactions_Id] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                      OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO TB_Transactions (TransferFromId, TransferToId, Amount, Created)
VALUES
     (17,18,5.00000000,'2022-06-22 16:19:19.8960000'),
     (21,17,12.00000000,'2022-06-01 02:04:27.3970000'),
     (14,19,10.00000000,'2022-05-03 15:43:47.0680000'),
     (15,20,23.00000000,'2022-06-07 11:34:32.1580000'),
     (12,21,100.00000000,'2022-05-05 02:54:57.7000000'),
     (15,14,20.00000000,'2022-06-24 12:57:41.0670000'),
     (19,20,43.00000000,'2022-06-10 00:46:35.3150000'),
     (21,17,54.00000000,'2022-05-05 00:18:24.6590000'),
     (15,18,28.00000000,'2022-05-02 22:06:25.3310000'),
     (13,15,62.00000000,'2022-05-06 00:05:51.2740000'),
     (15,NULL,2.00000000,'2022-06-01 01:05:51.2710000'),
     (NULL,17,3.00000000,'2022-06-02 02:05:51.2770000'),
     (19,NULL,20.00000000,'2022-07-02 02:05:45.2000000'),
     (15,19,50.00000000,'2022-07-08 07:05:40.2000000'),
     (14,21,10.00000000,'2022-07-07 08:05:40.2000000'),
     (14,21,10.00000000,'2022-07-08 09:05:40.2010000');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nested an outer SELECT to sum the amount, a quirk from SQL Server, but your sample data has no such result sets

> ```
> SELECT *  FROM TB_Transactions ft
>  WHERE  (SELECT SUM(myamount)
>           FROM
>               (SELECT iif(ft2.TransferFromId=ft.TransferFromId,-ft2.Amount,ft2.Amount) myamount
>        from TB_Transactions ft2
>        WHERE (ft2.TransferFromId =ft.TransferFromId
>           or  ft2.TransferToId = ft.TransferFromId)
>          and ft2.Created <= ft.Created) t1 )   = 0
> ```

> ```
> Id | TransferFromId | TransferToId |      Amount | Created                    
> -: | -------------: | -----------: | ----------: | :--------------------------
> 15 |             14 |           21 | 10.00000000 | 2022-07-07 08:05:40.2000000
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *,(SELECT SUM(myamount)
>           FROM
>               (SELECT iif(ft2.TransferFromId=ft.TransferFromId,-ft2.Amount,ft2.Amount) myamount
>        from TB_Transactions ft2
>        WHERE (ft2.TransferFromId =ft.TransferFromId
>           or  ft2.TransferToId = ft.TransferFromId)
>          and ft2.Created <= ft.Created) t1 ) test   FROM TB_Transactions ft
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | TransferFromId | TransferToId |       Amount | Created                     |          test
> -: | -------------: | -----------: | -----------: | :-------------------------- | ------------:
>  1 |             17 |           18 |   5.00000000 | 2022-06-22 16:19:19.8960000 |   64.00000000
>  2 |             21 |           17 |  12.00000000 | 2022-06-01 02:04:27.3970000 |   34.00000000
>  3 |             14 |           19 |  10.00000000 | 2022-05-03 15:43:47.0680000 |  -10.00000000
>  4 |             15 |           20 |  23.00000000 | 2022-06-07 11:34:32.1580000 |    9.00000000
>  5 |             12 |           21 | 100.00000000 | 2022-05-05 02:54:57.7000000 | -100.00000000
>  6 |             15 |           14 |  20.00000000 | 2022-06-24 12:57:41.0670000 |  -11.00000000
>  7 |             19 |           20 |  43.00000000 | 2022-06-10 00:46:35.3150000 |  -33.00000000
>  8 |             21 |           17 |  54.00000000 | 2022-05-05 00:18:24.6590000 |  -54.00000000
>  9 |             15 |           18 |  28.00000000 | 2022-05-02 22:06:25.3310000 |  -28.00000000
> 10 |             13 |           15 |  62.00000000 | 2022-05-06 00:05:51.2740000 |  -62.00000000
> 11 |             15 |         null |   2.00000000 | 2022-06-01 01:05:51.2710000 |   32.00000000
> 12 |           null |           17 |   3.00000000 | 2022-06-02 02:05:51.2770000 |          null
> 13 |             19 |         null |  20.00000000 | 2022-07-02 02:05:45.2000000 |  -53.00000000
> 14 |             15 |           19 |  50.00000000 | 2022-07-08 07:05:40.2000000 |  -61.00000000
> 15 |             14 |           21 |  10.00000000 | 2022-07-07 08:05:40.2000000 |    0.00000000
> 16 |             14 |           21 |  10.00000000 | 2022-07-08 09:05:40.2010000 |  -10.00000000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02d841e1b34afefbd00c0cb6e9b7c2fe)***strong text**

Comment: There are necessary records in the test data. Expected Result.
14| 21| 10.00000000| 1|2022-07-07 08:05:40.200|

Because the first transaction (transfer 10) for account 14: 0-10=-10
Second transaction (getting 20) for account 14: -10 +20=10
Third transaction (transfer 10) for account 14: 10 -10=0
Fourth transaction (transfer 10) for account 14: 0 -10=-10

Comment: look you had an error message i told you haw you can rid of it your subquery produces following result https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae79b4b7ec39c85f6abb0d1c969d389a so your subquery is wrong, but know you can look for the logic error,

Comment: rewriting your query i also can't find any id that have 0 as sum https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8a7f2789e193f6bd2bd8bbdf9037cc6

Comment: If only I knew how to write the correct query.
For account 14, a subquery that adds up to 0
maybe that will make it clearer. sorry. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=14098cb6a9628c65da6dd595a1dcfc3d

Comment: Account transactions 14. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e21a193ad4f9bb37ea8eba1e0995c4b9

Comment: i edited my answer, you hasd a bug in your code it must be  `(ft2.TransferFromId =ft.TransferFromId
          or  ft2.TransferToId = ft.TransferFromId)`

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has weird rules surrounding usage of outer references (such as `ft.TransferFromId`) in aggregations (such as `SUM`) inside correlated subqueries. You cannot use such a reference unless it is *outside* the aggregation.

A workaround is to `CROSS APPLY` the outer reference inside the subquery, so that it appears as part of the subquery scope.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TB_Transactions ft
WHERE (SELECT SUM(IIF(ft2.TransferFromId = v.TransferFromId, -ft2.Amount, ft2.Amount))
       from TB_Transactions ft2
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES( ft.TransferFromId )) v(TransferFromId)
       WHERE (ft2.TransferFromId = ft.TransferFromId
          or  ft2.TransferToId = ft.TransferToId)
         and ft2.Created <= ft.Created
      ) = 0;
```

Alternatively, you can apply the `IIF` value

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TB_Transactions ft
WHERE (SELECT SUM(v.value)
       from TB_Transactions ft2
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES( IIF(ft2.TransferFromId = ft.TransferFromId, -ft2.Amount, ft2.Amount) )) v(value)
       WHERE (ft2.TransferFromId = ft.TransferFromId
          or  ft2.TransferToId = ft.TransferToId)
         and ft2.Created <= ft.Created
      ) = 0;
```

The phrasing of the error message is unfortunate, as "Multiple columns" is not necessary to trigger the error.

---

Given your actual stated requirement of creating a running total, you can use a window function for this, by first unpivoting each row into a positive (for the receiver) and negative (for the sender).

```sql
WITH Running AS (
    SELECT *,
      RunningSum = SUM(v.DiffQty) OVER (PARTITION BY v.Transferrer ORDER BY ft.Created ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM TB_Transactions ft
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        (TransferFromId, -ft.Amount),
        (TransferToId,    ft.Amount)
    ) v(Transferrer, DiffQty)
),
PerId AS (
    SELECT *,
      Count = COUNT(CASE WHEN RunningSum = 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Transferrer)
    FROM Running
)
SELECT *
FROM PerId
WHERE Count > 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1a3df17a40d9eb13e3f889070cf7de9a)

Comment: I am new to SQL, so I did not correctly formulate what I want to get. Target:
Display all fields from the TB_Transactions for those transactions after which the sender's(TransferFromId) account had 0

Comment: So what about this doesn't work? I don't have your data so can't test. Please [edit] the question and supply sample data and expected results as text

Comment: Does not work.
Added table and data.

Comment: The error at least is solved https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7bb570072c28e742c7bc379276dfb2b5 as to the logic it looks like you should really be using window functions, something like this perhaps https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=79eccbff06ac61596ea7fe3a79932327

Comment: In this form, there is no error, but the corrected query does not solve the task either. I think window functions are not needed here, in theory everything should be simpler.

Comment: Like I said, I need expected results also (an explanation of the logic desired would also help, as it seems unclear).

Comment: Expected Result.
14| 21| 10.00000000| 1|2022-07-07 08:05:40.200|

Because the first transaction (transfer 10) for account 14: 0-10=-10
Second transaction (getting 20) for account 14: -10 +20=10
Third transaction (transfer 10) for account 14: 10 -10=0
Fourth transaction (transfer 10) for account 14: 0 -10=-10

Comment: Please put that within your question, not as a comment. So you want *all* transactions for an ID which equals 0? The second link I gave above will only give the transaction that reached 0. Something like this perhaps https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1a3df17a40d9eb13e3f889070cf7de9a?

Comment: We need all transactions after which the account will have 0.
Those. for each account, we summarize the amount of the current transaction and all previous ones. If the sum of transactions is 0, then this is what we need.